# How to make chart text responsive in Apex Chart

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

How to make that text in the bar responsive or how do i convert it to K or M? i try to use this code but it only change the side text

```
yaxis: {
   labels: {
     formatter: function(value) {
       if (isNumeric(value)) {
         return convertNumber(value)
       } else {
         return value
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

[image: img]

Comment: To format the text on top of the bars (the datalabels) use `dataLabels: formatter`, see the [docs](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/datalabels/)